# What kinds of PRNG exist outside Linear congruential generators?

Tags: random-generation

I'm kinda running out of words, Linear congruential generator are really low quality PRNG but it was all I needed for some basic stuff, now I need to fill the blank and get to know other families of PRNG but I don't have any idea about what are all the available families of PRNGs.

Someone can possibly write the hierarchy or the list of all the possible kinds of PRNGs out there ?

Comment: there are problems with this question ?

Comment: You might find this review article helpful: http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/handstat.pdf

Comment: You will also find this review of interest: http://www.docin.com/p-386134147.html